# How to find particular solution when only one solution of reduced equation is known?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In second order linear non homogeneous equation.
Suppose by inspection we know  one solution of its reduced equation (Homo).
Now if we want to find the particular solution of our ode, can we directly get it?
Is there a formula.
Sometimes we are only interested in the particular solution, so the procedure of first finding second solution of reduced equation and then using variation of parameters to get the desired solution will be tedious.

Comment: If your coefficients are constants and the equation is not homogeneous you could use the method of similarity. But in general if you have an equation like $a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)=A(x)$ I'd use the Lagrange's method to solve it... I know it's tedious.

Comment: If u really need a "formula", u can construct one by using the method of "reduction of order" (see, for example the section (ix) in the book [P. Hartman, Ordinary Differential Equations, 2nd Ed., Classics in Applied Mathematics, SIAM, pp 327]) and "variation of parameteres formula".